# send_keys() method of selenium python not working sometimes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

`send_keys()` method of selenium python not working sometimes. Keys that I send and the the ones that selected are different sometimes. This usually happens when it takes too long for the page to load.

I Tried using sleep before sending the keys for the element to load all the drop down values but this too doesn't work.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Tag")))
sleep(10)
self.driver.find_element_by_id('Tag').send_keys('Key Value')
```

Comment: Which web driver (including version) and browser (including version) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code helps in getting the particular option getting selected,

```
    select2=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ID_Name")))
    for item2 in select2.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        if item2.text.strip() == 'Option Name':
            item2.click()
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

As you intend to use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) before invoking `send_keys()` instead of [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as `visibility_of_element_located()` you need to use `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Tag"))).send_keys("Key Value")
```

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you very much

Comment: Still the problem of different key getting selected persists. Is there any other workaround to fix this